# saving PFObject in backgrounds

Tags: xcode, swift, pfobject

in my app when i try to sign up the PFObjects are not saved in background (emailLabel, FirstNameLabel, LastNameLabel, PasswordLabel. any idea why

Here is is a code snippet

```
@IBAction func NextSignupPage(sender: AnyObject) {


let FirstNameObject = PFObject(className: "\(self.FirstNameLabel.text)")
FirstNameObject["First Name"] = "\(self.FirstNameLabel.text)"
FirstNameObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    }

let FamilyNameObject = PFObject(className: "\(self.FamilyNameLabel.text)")
FamilyNameObject["Family Name"] = "\(self.FamilyNameLabel.text)"
FamilyNameObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    }

let PasswordObject = PFObject(className: "\(self.PasswordLabel.text)")
PasswordObject["password"] = "\(self.PasswordLabel.text)"
PasswordObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
println("successfully signed Up.")
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: You should be using `PFUser` here -> https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users

Comment: `println(error)` and see what error you are getting. There could be rights issues or perhaps a column naming problem. Hard to tell from just this code.

Comment: i shoud have used pfuser()

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems that I see that might be causing the issues you are experiencing. First, as mentioned in the comments by flashadvanced, you should be using the Parse provided `user.signUpInBackground` to sign up new users. (Most importantly because Parse will encrypt your user's passwords. It seems as though you are planning on storing them as regular strings.) The docs to accomplish this can be found [here.](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users)

In regards to creating `PFObjects` in general, it seems as though you want to create one `PFObject` that store the first name, family name and password. Your code above will create three different `PFObjects` that have no relationship to one another. In addition, you supply three different classes to the different `PFObjects`, another reason why they will not show up in the same class on the Parse server. The correct way of accomplishing this (considering that you should still be using the `.signUpInBackground` method and this applies only to other non- specific `PFObjects`) would be:

```
    let object = PFObject(className: "YourClassName")
    object["First Name"] = "\(self.FirstNameLabel.text)"
    object["Family Name"] = "\(self.FamilyNameLabel.text)"
    object["password"] = "\(self.PasswordLabel.text)"
    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("successfully signed Up.")
    }
```